# Is it possible to access the session variable between two simulation files in gatling using scala?

Tags: simulation, gatling

is there a way to access the session variable from one simulation file to an another simulation file. I can access session variable inside scenarios within the same simulation file as below and it works fine.  As OrderId should be created only one in my usecase, i cant recreate the order in the second simulation file, hence i need to reuse OrderId and OrderUri in the second simulation file from the previous first simulation file.
Will the session be accessible between simulation once it is set using session => session.setAll()? Can you please advise?

```
 SimulationFile_1
    
              var OrderId = ""
              var OrderUri = ""
            
                private val order: ScenarioBuilder =
                    scenario("order creation")
                      .exec(createorders)
                      .exec(submitOrders)
                      .exec(session => {
                        OrderId = session("OrderId").as[String].trim
                        OrderUri = session("OrderUri").as[String].trim
                        println(session)
                        session
                      })
                
                  private val openRound: ScenarioBuilder =
                    scenario("Open Bidding")
                      .exec(session => session.setAll(Map("OrderId" -> OrderId, "OrderUri" -> OrderUri)))
                      .exec(placeOrder)
                      .exec(addOrder)
            
    
    **SimulationFile_1** setup looks like below.
       
    

 setUp(
        order.inject(
          nothingFor(1),
          atOnceUsers(1),
        ).andThen(openRound.inject(nothingFor(1),
          atOnceUsers(1)).
          andThen(order_round1.inject(nothingFor(1),
            atOnceUsers(1),
            rampUsers(1).during(50))).
          andThen(closeRound.inject(nothingFor(1),
            atOnceUsers(1))))
    

    I should not be calling order api again, should reuse the same order id from the previous rest call.(previous simulation file)
       
    
     **SimulationFile_2**
                                                                                    
setUp(                                                                         
       openRound.inject(                                                       
         nothingFor(1),                                                        
         atOnceUsers(1),                                                       
       ).andThen(order_round2.inject(nothingFor(1),                            
           atOnceUsers(1),                                                     
           rampUsers(1).during(50)).                                           
         andThen(closeRound2.inject(nothingFor(1),                             
           atOnceUsers(1)))))
```

**edit:**

```
 .exec(session => {                                                                                                                                
     val writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("src/gatling/resources/data/myFile.csv"), true))                                        
     writer.write(session("orderId").as[String] + "," + session("OrderUri").as[String] + "," + session("OrderYear").as[String])        
     writer.write("\n")                                                                                                                            
     writer.close()                                                                                                                                
     session                                                                                                                                       
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Different Gatling simulations live in different JVM instances, so you would need some external persistent store: a file, Redis, etc.

Comment: Can you please advise how to store the session variable in the file to use in the second simulation file ? can you please assist me with an example or any reference? I am using scala.

Comment: Writing and writing into a file is basic Java and doesn’t require any Scala knowledge.

Comment: I just updated my question, I exported session variables into the file, but not sure how i can read the file - values now inside gatling tests, as the file has only values and doesnt have any headers, how i should be reading inside the test? https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/feeder/#file-based-feeders.       when i tried something like this, val file = new File("src/gatling/resources/myFile.csv") and feed(file) it gives me an error -cannot resolve overloaded method feed.

Comment: val file =  csv("data/Bases-Round-1.csv") --> I updated like this, and used feed(file) -however the file doesnt have any headers, it has only orderId and orderURI,year values. do i have to add headers to the csv file while writing date into file to start using inside gatling test?

Comment: Gatling built-in CSV feeder requires the header line, yes. Either generate it, or use your own file reader code.